# Why are all involutions conjugate in the special linear group of degree 2?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, involutions

It appears to be standard that the set of non-identity involutions in $SL(2, 2^n) = PSL(2, 2^n)$ forms a single conjugacy class. What is the best reference for this?

I note that 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208255/conjugacy-classes-of-elements-of-a-prime-order-in-psl-2q
asked a related question and seems to contain a proof, but is there a published proof?

Comment: There are many published proofs.  This was first done by Dickson, you can see his 1901 book "Linear Groups".  More recent expositions include Suzuki's book "Group Theory I" (section III.6) and Gorenstein's "Finite Groups" (section 2.8).

Comment: -1 Sorry, but mathoverflow is thought for research level questions. Please ask this kind of question at math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The comment above gives a few references. The most straightforward proof of this specific question seems to be Lemma (6.3) in "Group Theory I" by Suzuki.

Comment: Yes, it is easy to see directly. Setting $q = 2^{n},$ the normalizer of a Sylow $2$-subgroup has order $q(q-1),$ and contains a cyclic subgroup of order $q-1$ which permutes the non-identity elements of the Sylow $2$-subgroup transitively under conjugation.